# Excel Graph - Category and Subcategory grouping

Tags: excel, graph, statistics

I seldom if ever use excel and have no deep understanding of graphs and graphing-related functions. Having said that...

I have dozens of rows of data, composed by 4 columns

- column 1 = amount/price (in numbers)
- column 2 = description (the what
  in text)
- column 3 = category (in text)
- column 4 = subcategory (in
  text)

I want to make a bar graph of my rows of data so that, the end result looks like this:

X axis - categories
Y axis - amount/price

The trick here is for categories NOT to repeat themselves. For example, if our data is something like...

- 100 | boat purchase | boats | 3 engine boat
- 200 | boat purchase |
  boats | 2 engine boat
- 500 | plane purchase | planes | 4 engine plane
- 900 | car purchase | cars | 1 engine car

Then there should only be ONE instance of boats, planes and cars in my graph, under which all associated data would be summed up.

Last but not least, I have seen graphs where, these unique-not-repeated categories, instead of just being one single 'bar' so to speak, are composed of smaller bars. In this case, I want these smaller bars to be the sub categories, so that the end result would look like this:

[image: basic and complex graph samples]

In that sample image, I first present a 'basic, classic' graph where blue, yellow and red each represent a unique, different category. Right below it is what I want, a 'breakdown' of each category by subcategory where blue/yellow/red each represent an imaginary 3 different subcategories per category.

This means subcategories will repeat themselves for each category, but categories themselves will not.

For clarification, I currently only have 3 main categories and 6 or so sub-categories, but this could change in the future, hence the desire to have this in an automatic/dynamic fashion

Kind regards
G.Campos

EDIT: new image:

[image: better explanation of desired graph result]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here i my take on it. Unfortunately I can't post the screenshots as I don't have enough posts.

One solution is to use pivot charts put Amount in "Values", Category in "Row Lables", and SubCategory in "Column Labels".

I uploaded relevant images on a free image upload service.

This is our source data:

```
Amount  Decription  Category    SubCategory
100     boat purchase   boats   3 engine boat
200     boat purchase   boats   2 engine boat
500     plane purchase  planes  4 engine plane
900     car purchase    cars    1 engine car
450     boat purchase   boats   2 engine boat
110     plane purchase  planes  4 engine plane
550     car purchase    cars    1 engine car
230     car purchase    cars    2 engine car
450     car purchase    cars    5 engine car
```

This is the desired graph (Edit: This has ghost bars):

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/pivot.gif/

I just read the comment about no ghost graphs. This might be what you are looking for:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/266/pivotnoghost.gif/

Just googled and found something very similar here:

peltiertech.com/WordPress/using-pivot-table-data-for-a-chart-with-a-dual-category-axis/

You need to add http:// ( I can't have more than two hyperlinks due to low number of posts)

Comment: Nice, how did you achieve the last screenshot though? (removing ghost graphs) so that I can award you the answer+rep points. Thanks

Comment: place both category and sub-category in axis field. please zoom into the graph image and you will see the required format on the lower right side.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this will get you exactly where you want but I find in general in excel it is easiest to summarize your graph data on a separate tab.

For sample data like this

[image: dataset]

you would create a 2nd tab in the sheet that appears something like

[image: summary data]

the totals are calculated by using the sumif formula

```
=SUMIF(Data!C:C,Summary!A2,Data!A:A)
```

For the Category totals

and

```
=SUMIF(Data!D:D,Summary!E2,Data!A:A)
```

For the sub category totals (Assuming sub-categories are mutally exclusive). Now that that data is summarized, highlight the cells and insert a column chart for the following charts.

[image: pretty charts]

Adding new categories and/or sub categories will require you to add lines to the summary data, and then add series to the charts. You could use a vba macro to automate that task but I suspect that is overkill since your dataset is "dozens" rather than "thousands"

Comment: The thing with your last graph is that the subcategories of each category are not grouped together. That's what boggles me with this particular desired effect I seek. I swear I've seen it done before (back when I didn't have to work with graphs ironically) but I can't remember a concrete URL or example to point to.

Comment: Grouping them together is possible, but your sample data leads me to think that the resulting output is less useful. The complicating issue the that your sub categories are mutually exclusive, so formatting the graph to group sub categories together will cause your boat category to have a space on the bar graph for 1 engine Car sub category (which by definition will be 0). Hopefully that clarifies somewhat.... if not let me know and I will modify the answer above.

Comment: I admit I wasn't very clear with my explanation. I have added another image/sketch to further clarify things. Thanks again Pynner

Comment: Ok basically, each category may or may not have all the subcategories, it doesn't matter. Only those that do 'apply' so to speak should be included, which means there shouldn't be empty or ghost graphs